# How to increase the font size/ better render Pandas dataframes in Jupyter Notebooks opened in VS Code?

Tags: pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Is there a way to change how Pandas dataframes are rendered in output cells of Jupyter Notebooks opened in VS Code? By default, the font of the dataframe output is small, regardless of my VS code settings (see 1). In addition, I'd like for the dateframes to render more like the default rendering in native Jupyter notebook opened in a browser (see 2). Does anyone know how to make VS code change the dataframe rendering. Is there something I need to change in settings?

1. Notebook in VS Code:
   [image: VS Code]
2. Notebook in Chrome:
   [image: Jupyter in Chrome]
3. Edit: Using print(df) only increases the font size to match my font settings, but doesn't change the appearance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these two new settings in vscode v1.67 will help:

`notebook.outputFontSize`, "Font size for plain text outputs. When set to 0 `#editor.fontSize#` is used."

`notebook.outputFontFamily`, "The font family for plain text output of notebook cells. When set to empty, the `#editor.fontFamily#` is used."

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147321/commits/51ab78f535d8537e031e1ae77cac678ae22b0249